# Is there a ps command or a python module/command that can enable/disable the wifi properties for windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, powershell

more specifically i need to enable/disable the "allow other network users to connect through this internet connection" in the the wifi properties section.

Theres a similair question already but i tried the answers it doesnt work, so i added custom python module in hopes of there being one

The Box
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVGlB.png

Answer (score 0):

On windows, these kinds of changes are usually done through Group Policy. The policy object that defines that is named "Prohibit use of Internet Connection Sharing on your DNS domain network". Check the [admx.help](https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.NetworkConnections::NC_ShowSharedAccessUI) page for details. It's located under

```
Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/Network/Network Connections
```

Policies can be set manually through python or powershell by setting registry values like this, but group policy refreshes can overwrite them later:

```
New-ItemProperty 'hklm:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Network Connections\' -Name NC_ShowSharedAccessUI -Value 0
```

You can also just stop and disable the internet connection sharing service:

```
Set-Service -Name icssvc -StartupType Disabled
Stop-Service -Name icssvc
```